# MVC filters default implementation

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

Is there any default implementation for the filters (Authentication,Authorization,Action,Exception filters) provided in asp.net mvc?

Comment: This questions was asked to my friend during his interview.Was surprised by looking at down vote without explanation :(

Comment: Not sure about all of them, but some of them definitely have some default implementation. For example, the `HandleErrorAttribute` shows the error view in /Views/Shared `OnException` by default. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-in/library/system.web.mvc.handleerrorattribute(v=vs.100).aspx